# why isn't the footer tag at the bottom of the div?

Tags: html, css

**Flex and footer problem**

i would like it to be like the picture
footer at the bottom of my div
I have to use flex tags I looked for solution on this website but didn't find one that fit to my code
could someone help me please?

I'm a beginner in CSS flex elements

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  margin-left: 10%;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

p {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  margin: 10px;
}

section {
  border: 6px solid rgb(231, 198, 106);
  border-radius: 2px;
  max-width: 30%;
  width: auto;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

section>footer {
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0px;
}

header>h1 {
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: orange;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">

<head>
  <!-- Entête  -->
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Mes articles</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css7.1.css">
</head>

<body>
  <!-- contenu -->
  <!-- flex: 1; pour occuper l'espace restant -->

  <h1> Mes articles </h1>
  <div class="container">
    <section>
      <header>
        <h1>Article un </h1>
      </header>
      <div class="content">
        <p>
          Chaque section occupe environ 1/3 de la largeur totale <br>Le pied de section s'affiche toujours en bas.
        </p>
      </div>
      <!-- /content -->

      <footer>footer</footer>
    </section>

    <section>
      <header>
        <h1>Article deux</h1>
      </header>
      <div class="content">
        <p>
          Suspendisse potenti. In et dignissim sapien, ac porttitor urna. Curabitur finibus dolor at quam suscipit, non ultrices diam interdum. Donec ante magna, interdum ac porttitor ac, pellentesque a nulla. Fusce tellus ex, congue eget rhoncus ut, porttitor
          eu tortor. Sed vehicula scelerisque lectus eu imperdiet. Sed velit diam, lacinia eget felis vitae, ullamcorper condimentum nisi. Mauris pretium imperdiet augue ac venenatis. Integer sit amet ornare nunc. Vestibulum rhoncus tempor ipsum. Mauris
          et ultrices metus. Nam sit amet egestas sem, et hendrerit mi.
        </p>
      </div>
      <!-- /content -->

      <footer>footer</footer>
    </section>

    <section>
      <header>
        <h1>Article trois</h1>
      </header>
      <div class="content">
        <p>
          Suspendisse potenti. In et dignissim sapien, ac porttitor urna. Curabitur finibus dolor at quam suscipit, non ultrices diam interdum. Donec ante magna, interdum ac porttitor ac, pellentesque a nulla.
        </p>
      </div>
      <!-- /content -->

      <footer>footer<br>sur 2 lignes</footer>
    </section>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

[[image]]

I would like it to be like the picture
footer at the bottom of my div
I have to use flex tags I looked for solution on this website but didn't find one that fit to my code
could someone help me please?

I'm a beginner in CSS flex elements

Answer (score 1):

I believe `section` should be column `flex` container and `.content` be the one to stretch via `flex-grow` :

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  margin-left: 10%;
}

section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.content {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

p {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  margin: 10px;
}

section {
  border: 6px solid rgb(231, 198, 106);
  border-radius: 2px;
  max-width: 30%;
  width: auto;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

section>footer {
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0px;
}

header>h1 {
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: orange;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">

<head>
  <!-- Entête  -->
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Mes articles</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css7.1.css">
</head>

<body>
  <!-- contenu -->
  <!-- flex: 1; pour occuper l'espace restant -->

  <h1> Mes articles </h1>
  <div class="container">
    <section>
      <header>
        <h1>Article un </h1>
      </header>
      <div class="content">
        <p>
          Chaque section occupe environ 1/3 de la largeur totale <br>Le pied de section s'affiche toujours en bas.
        </p>
      </div>
      <!-- /content -->

      <footer>footer</footer>
    </section>

    <section>
      <header>
        <h1>Article deux</h1>
      </header>
      <div class="content">
        <p>
          Suspendisse potenti. In et dignissim sapien, ac porttitor urna. Curabitur finibus dolor at quam suscipit, non ultrices diam interdum. Donec ante magna, interdum ac porttitor ac, pellentesque a nulla. Fusce tellus ex, congue eget rhoncus ut, porttitor
          eu tortor. Sed vehicula scelerisque lectus eu imperdiet. Sed velit diam, lacinia eget felis vitae, ullamcorper condimentum nisi. Mauris pretium imperdiet augue ac venenatis. Integer sit amet ornare nunc. Vestibulum rhoncus tempor ipsum. Mauris
          et ultrices metus. Nam sit amet egestas sem, et hendrerit mi.
        </p>
      </div>
      <!-- /content -->

      <footer>footer</footer>
    </section>

    <section>
      <header>
        <h1>Article trois</h1>
      </header>
      <div class="content">
        <p>
          Suspendisse potenti. In et dignissim sapien, ac porttitor urna. Curabitur finibus dolor at quam suscipit, non ultrices diam interdum. Donec ante magna, interdum ac porttitor ac, pellentesque a nulla.
        </p>
      </div>
      <!-- /content -->

      <footer>footer<br>sur 2 lignes</footer>
    </section>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Other possibility with `section` being the `flex` container is to use `margin` on the `footer` so it sends itself all the way to the bottom.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  margin-left: 10%;
}

section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

footer {
  margin-top:auto;
}

p {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  margin: 10px;
}

section {
  border: 6px solid rgb(231, 198, 106);
  border-radius: 2px;
  max-width: 30%;
  width: auto;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

section>footer {
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0px;
}

header>h1 {
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: orange;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">

<head>
  <!-- Entête  -->
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Mes articles</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css7.1.css">
</head>

<body>
  <!-- contenu -->
  <!-- flex: 1; pour occuper l'espace restant -->

  <h1> Mes articles </h1>
  <div class="container">
    <section>
      <header>
        <h1>Article un </h1>
      </header>
      <div class="content">
        <p>
          Chaque section occupe environ 1/3 de la largeur totale <br>Le pied de section s'affiche toujours en bas.
        </p>
      </div>
      <!-- /content -->

      <footer>footer</footer>
    </section>

    <section>
      <header>
        <h1>Article deux</h1>
      </header>
      <div class="content">
        <p>
          Suspendisse potenti. In et dignissim sapien, ac porttitor urna. Curabitur finibus dolor at quam suscipit, non ultrices diam interdum. Donec ante magna, interdum ac porttitor ac, pellentesque a nulla. Fusce tellus ex, congue eget rhoncus ut, porttitor
          eu tortor. Sed vehicula scelerisque lectus eu imperdiet. Sed velit diam, lacinia eget felis vitae, ullamcorper condimentum nisi. Mauris pretium imperdiet augue ac venenatis. Integer sit amet ornare nunc. Vestibulum rhoncus tempor ipsum. Mauris
          et ultrices metus. Nam sit amet egestas sem, et hendrerit mi.
        </p>
      </div>
      <!-- /content -->

      <footer>footer</footer>
    </section>

    <section>
      <header>
        <h1>Article trois</h1>
      </header>
      <div class="content">
        <p>
          Suspendisse potenti. In et dignissim sapien, ac porttitor urna. Curabitur finibus dolor at quam suscipit, non ultrices diam interdum. Donec ante magna, interdum ac porttitor ac, pellentesque a nulla.
        </p>
      </div>
      <!-- /content -->

      <footer>footer<br>sur 2 lignes</footer>
    </section>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to put `align-items: flex-start;` on the .container where the display:flex is.

The default align-items is stretch, that is why is stretches until the bottom.

Also, you can explore `align-items: flex-end;` and `align-items: center;`.

```css
.container{
    display:flex;
    margin-left: 10%;
    align-items: flex-start;
}
.content{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    
}
p{
    word-wrap: break-word;
    margin:10px;
    
}

section{
    border: 6px solid rgb(231, 198, 106);
    border-radius: 2px;
    max-width: 30%;
    width: auto;
    margin-right: 10px;
}


section>footer{
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 2px;
    
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    color:white;
    
    
}

h1{
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0px;
}
header>h1{
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: orange;
    color:white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
   <head>
      <!-- Entête  -->
      <meta charset="utf-8"/>
      <title>Mes articles</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css7.1.css">
   </head>
   <body>
      <!-- contenu -->
      <!-- flex: 1; pour occuper l'espace restant -->

      <h1> Mes articles </h1>
      <div class="container">
            <section>
                <header>
                <h1>Article un </h1>
                </header>
                <div class="content">
                <p>
                Chaque section occupe environ 1/3 de la largeur
                totale <br>Le pied de section s'affiche toujours en bas.
                </p> 
                </div> <!-- /content -->

                <footer>footer</footer>
            </section>

            <section>
                <header>
                <h1>Article deux</h1>
                </header>
                <div class="content" >
                <p>
                    Suspendisse potenti. In et dignissim sapien, ac
                porttitor urna. Curabitur finibus dolor at quam suscipit,
                non ultrices diam interdum. Donec ante magna, interdum ac
                porttitor ac, pellentesque a nulla. Fusce tellus ex,
                congue eget rhoncus ut, porttitor eu tortor. Sed vehicula
                scelerisque lectus eu imperdiet. Sed velit diam, lacinia
                eget felis vitae, ullamcorper condimentum nisi. Mauris
                pretium imperdiet augue ac venenatis. Integer sit amet
                ornare nunc. Vestibulum rhoncus tempor ipsum. Mauris et
                ultrices metus. Nam sit amet egestas sem, et hendrerit
                mi.
                </p> 
                </div> <!-- /content -->

                <footer>footer</footer>
            </section>

            <section>
                <header>
                <h1>Article trois</h1>
                </header>
                <div class="content" >
                <p>
                Suspendisse potenti. In et dignissim sapien, ac
                porttitor urna. Curabitur finibus dolor at quam suscipit,
                non ultrices diam interdum. Donec ante magna, interdum ac
                porttitor ac, pellentesque a nulla.
                </p> 
                </div> <!-- /content -->

                <footer>footer<br>sur 2 lignes</footer>
            </section>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```